How to Manage Environment-Specific Database Connection URLs in a Shopify Remix App on Fly.io
I'm developing a Shopify app using Remix and deploying it to Fly.io. To connect to my database, I'm using connection URLs stored in a .env file. However, I have separate URLs for development and production environments. Manually changing the URL in the .env file before deployment is cumbersome.
Is there a way to automatically configure the database connection URL based on the current environment (development or production) in my Shopify Remix app deployed on Fly.io?
schema.prisma file:-
datasource db {
  provider  = "postgresql"
  url       = env("POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL")
  directUrl = env("POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING")
}


After conducting some research, I found the solution. I added two variables, POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL and POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING, to my fly.io Secrets. Additionally, I included the local database URL in my project's .env file. Now, whenever I run the deploy command, it automatically takes the production URL.
